# How do I login to Ubuntu Forums using OpenID?

Tags: login, ubuntu-forums

I haven't been on ubuntuforums.org for ages, but I came across a thread from a search. Annoyingly, the forums require to be logged in to view images! So I tried to login.

I was looking for a login field to enter my OpenID URL (https://launchpad.net/~james.r.haigh), but I couldn't find anything. I'm pretty sure there used to be something obvious like ‘Login via OpenID’.

I tried entering my URL in the username field, but as expected it didn't work.

Comment: I found the info I needed elsewhere in the end, but it's still a shame that I couldn't login. They need to fix this a.s.a.p., and preferably also allow viewing of images without logging in.

Answer (score 4):

There was an OpenID login option.

It got lost by IS when the forum upgraded from vb3 to vb4.

There is a plan to use SSO - but that as well was not brought in to the upgrade by them.

It should be on their list of things to look at.

Comment: Gosh, that's ridiculous! They should have postponed the update until they fixed this major login issue!

Comment: Just realised that the forum software they use is proprietary, which surprises me since there are plenty of good Free forum softwares. What does ‘IS’ mean?

Comment: The forum upgrade waited for some years for the SSO plugin to be setup and created, once the upgrade took place then it didn't work. The people that created and wanted the SSO plugin to be used need to look at that, this was intended to replace the working OpenID login system. IS is Canonical's Internet Services. YEs the forum uses vBulletin, it has more or less always done so - this is well documented on the forum.

Answer (score 1):

As of this moment, login via openid is not working, it is under repair =)

Comment: Do you have any links?

Comment: No, sorry, could not find a formal ticket.